# how to sort the dictionary by value in python

Tags: python, sorting, dictionary

Trying to sort the below dictionary by accounts value but it's not shorting properly

```
{'Ith': {'users': '490', 'accounts': '1022'}, 'Al': {'users': '85', 'accounts': '145'}, 'Credit': {'users': '0', 'accounts': '0'}, 'Ahli': {'users': '68', 'accounts': '88'}, 'Standard': {'users': '76', 'accounts': '191'}, 'State': {'users': '1', 'accounts': '1'}, 'Bah': {'users': '58', 'accounts': '94'}, 'Kuw': {'users': '3', 'accounts': '7'}, 'Khal': {'users': '32', 'accounts': '54'}, 'National': {'users': '71', 'accounts': '90'}, 'Ban': {'users': '418', 'accounts': '817'}}

OrderedDict(sorted(a.items(), key=lambda i: i[1]['accounts'], reverse=True))
```

The result I am getting is

```
OrderedDict([('Bah', {'users': '58', 'accounts': '94'}), ('National', {'users': '71', 'accounts': '90'}), ('Ahli', {'users': '68', 'accounts': '88'}), ('Ban', {'users': '418', 'accounts': '817'}), ('Kuwe', {'users': '3', 'accounts': '7'}), ('Khal', {'users': '32', 'accounts': '54'}), ('Standard', {'users': '76', 'accounts': '191'}), ('Al', {'users': '85', 'accounts': '145'}), ('Ith', {'users': '490', 'accounts': '1022'}), ('State', {'users': '1', 'accounts': '1'}), ('Credit', {'users': '0', 'accounts': '0'})])
```

I need the result should be

```
{'Ith': {'users': '490', 'accounts': '1022'}, 'Ban': {'users': '418', 'accounts': '817'}, 'Standard': {'users': '76', 'accounts': '191'}, 'Al': {'users': '85', 'accounts': '145'}, 'Bah': {'users': '58', 'accounts': '94'}, 'National': {'users': '71', 'accounts': '90'}, 'Ahli': {'users': '68', 'accounts': '88'}, 'Khal': {'users': '32', 'accounts': '54'}, 'Kuw': {'users': '3', 'accounts': '7'}, 'State': {'users': '1', 'accounts': '1'}, 'Credit': {'users': '0', 'accounts': '0'}}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I sort a dictionary by value?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/613183/how-do-i-sort-a-dictionary-by-value)

Comment: I need to sort the dictionary by the value JSON account

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try using `key=lambda i: int(i[1]['accounts'])`. Your account "numbers" are *strings* which you were sorting lexicographically. If you want them to sort numerically, you have to convert them to numbers in your key function.

Comment: resolved my issue